# Java Hibernate Error

Tags: java

I want to insert to my postgresql database using hibernate and I quite or haven't figure out why I keep getting this error, What I'm trying to do is I let the hibernate create my database table and column and insert to the created table. So my first error is about the missing jar files which is the slf4j which I already added to my Hibernate library, However after I run the application again new error pops up so this are my error:

```
90 [main] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons 

Annotations 3.2.0.Final
100 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.6.10.Final
100 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
100 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
100 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
150 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
150 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2176)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2157)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2137)
    at org.hibernate_main.HibernateMain.main(HibernateMain.java:13)
```

This are my Jar File(int the Hibernate library):

```
hibernate3.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
jta-1.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4
```

And my code:
Configuration(XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- ~ Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java ~ ~ Copyright (c) 2010, Red Hat Inc. or third-party contributors as ~ indicated by the @author tags or express copyright attribution ~ statements applied by the authors. All third-party contributions are ~ distributed under license by Red Hat Inc. ~ ~ This copyrighted material is made available to anyone wishing to use, modify, ~ copy, or redistribute it subject to the terms and conditions of the GNU ~ Lesser General Public License, as published by the Free Software Foundation. ~ ~ This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, ~ but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY ~ or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Lesser General Public License ~ for more details. ~ ~ You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License ~ along with this distribution; if not, write to: ~ Free Software Foundation, Inc. ~ 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor ~ Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA -->

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN">
-<hibernate-configuration> -<session-factory> 
<!-- Database connection settings -->
 <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property> 
 <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432:MYPOS</property> 
 <property name="connection.username">postgres</property> 
 <property name="connection.password"/>perbert101
<!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
 <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property> 
<!-- SQL dialect -->
 <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property> 
<!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
 <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property> 
<!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
 <property name="show_sql">true</property> 
<!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
 <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> 
<!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
 <mapping class="org.user_detail.dto.UserDetail"/> </session-factory> </hibernate-configuration>
```

UserDetail Class:

```
package org.user_detail.dto;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class UserDetail {
    @Id
    private int userId;
    private String userName;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

}
```

My Main Class:

```
package org.hibernate_main;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.user_detail.dto.UserDetail;

public class HibernateMain {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        UserDetail user = new UserDetail();
        user.setUserId(1);
        user.setUserName("Jerome");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

Guys can you tell me what this error was and how to fix them, and how to test if the database connection in the XML is success or failed. thanks guys.

Comment: Where is your config file? And can you please edit out the non-essential info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
  /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
```

is clear enough.

Make sure it's in the CLASSPATH.

You can also specify it in:

```
return new Configuration().configure("/path/to/hibernate.cfg.xml" ).buildSessionFactory();
```

in your code above

Comment: yeah thank. my mistake :D i is name config it should be hibernate.

Comment: what does this error mean Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: it means it can't read the XML file because it contains error. There is a dash "-" here `-<hibernate-configuration>` and here `-<session-factory> ` and `<property name="connection.password"/>perbert101` doesn't have a closing tag

Comment: thanks it's working now it seems the problem is in the <!DOCTYPE> anyway thanks "D

Comment: I don't understand. Did this make Hibernate run higher version of Java than 1.4?